# Find documents by array of embedded references in Moongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Assuming I have the following collection schema

```
var terminalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: 'String', 
    ip: 'String'
});

var wayPointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: 'String',
    description: 'String',
    long: 'Number',
    lat: 'Number',
    distances: [{
        toTerminal : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Terminal' },
        km : 'Number',
        minutes: 'Number'
    }]
});
```

How can I find all WayPoints with terminal.ip = '10.0.0.1'

I have tried the following with no luck...

```
WayPoint.find()
.populate({
    path: 'distances.toTerminal',
    match:  { 'distances.toTerminal.ip': '10.0.0.1'},
})
.exec(function(err, wp) {
    if(err || !wp) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          console.log(wp);
        }
})
```

The entire collection is returned

**Update - Progress?**

I think I've made some progress with the following code, as it now only shows `[object]` for matching sub-documents and `null` for sub-documents that don't match.

```
WayPoint.find({'distances.toTerminal': {$exists: true}})
.populate({
    path: 'distances.toTerminal',
    select: 'description',
    match:  { ip: '10.0.0.1'}
})
.exec(function(err, wp) {
    if(err || !wp) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          console.log(wp);
        }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "match" part of `.populate()` here is not actually the "full" visualized path from the "WayPoint" object but actually only applies to the "Terminal" object. The "WayPoint" only has the reference so you do this:

```
WayPoint.find()
    .populate({
        "path": "distances.toTerminal",
        "match": { "ip": "10.0.0.1" }
    })
    .exec(function(err,wp) {
        if (err) throw err;  // or otherwise handle

        wp = wp.filter(function(doc) {
            doc.distances = doc.distances.filter(function(distance) {
                return distance.toTerminal != null;
            });
            return doc.distances.length > 0;
        });

        console.dir(wp);
    });
```

That really isn't a very efficient way to find a "WayPoint" by the "Terminal" ip value as mongoose actually fetches all "WayPoint" items and you have to "filter" yourself in order to find the ones that matched.

The better way would be to "embed" the document, then you can issue the top level query to find only documents that match:

```
WayPoint.find({ "distances.toTerminal.ip": "10.0.0.1" },function(err,wp) {
```

That is the general MongoDB way, but if you cannot do that or it is otherwise impractical, then you would be better of finding the `_id` of the matching "Terminal" object or objects and passing that to your "WayPoint" query. A little help from the "async" library to clean up the code:

```
async.waterfall(
    [
        function(callback) {
            Terminal.find({ "ip": "10.0.0.1" },function(err,terms) {
                if (err) throw err;
                ids = terms.map(function(term) { return term._id; });
                callback(err,ids);
            });
        },

        function(ids,callback) {
            WayPoint.find(
               { "distances.toTerminal": { "$in": ids } },
               function(err,wp) {
                   if (err) throw err;
                   console.dir( wp );
                   callback();
               }
            );
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: @NeilLuhn thanks for the comprehensive and prompt answer. The only reason I haven't embedded `Terminal` is for "reusability" across multiple waypoints. Would you suggest I retain the Terminal Schema so users could easily find the terminal, and then embed a "copy" of the `terminal` document into `WayPoint`?

Comment: @Habib That would be an option yes. As long as you can live with "updating" in multiple places when you need to. But the general point is if you want to query by "ip" or other information on that data then you want that to be accessible in your "WayPoint" object as the second query form shows. That is the most efficient way.